# Android application slide down menu

Tags: android, menu, slide

[image]

I've attached two images, one showing a closed menu and one showing the menu when opened. I know it's in an iPhone background but I am looking to do this for ANDROID.

I have had a few attempts at trying to recreate something similar but haven't quite got close enough yet.

Can anyone give me some suggestions on how I could maybe get this effect? I've tried using https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel and it's got me close but I'm not sold on if it's the option.

Just to be clear, the aim of the question is just for some ideas for how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Use a DialogFragment in fullscreen with transition animation from top to bottom and implement a callback interface for different actions. Or use a simple layout and position it where you want with animations.